# Exporting image into excel in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, excellibrary

I want to export my html page into excell sheet which contains some svg charts and html tables. I searched a lot and couldn't find any solution in javascript. I could find a php solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500323/export-html-table-to-excel-whit-text-and-images). Only thing i found is a node module([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excellent)) which i think cannot be used in a web page js file.

Comment: If you want to use Javascript node library is the only option. If you are using php phpexcel is the good option to export images into excel cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution for inserting image into excel in [Excelbuilder.js](http://excelbuilderjs.com/cookbook/insertingPictures.html).
We can insert image by specifying cell or offset positions using this plugin. It works.

Comment: this library is not working , i mean it seems it dead link now